# When i am creating ole db destination it shows error how can i solve it?

Tags: sql, ssis

The number column for hospital data.inputs[ole db destination input] cannot be zero
[image: the number column for hospital data.inputs[ole db destination input] cannot be zero]

Comment: More information, please!

Comment: i had attached a picture you can see from here

Comment: Actually i am creating a ETL project and i did it once! Unfortunately the project was deleted so now i am trying again ! Whenever i am going to connect ole db source with ole db destination it shows error like "the number column for hospital data.inputs[ole db destination input] cannot be zero"

Comment: Looks like it is a mapping issue, Can you check whether the input columns from the source file is mapped to OLE DB destination?

Comment: It looks like you havent mapped your source columns to your destination.

Comment: mapping done ! still its showing error :(

Comment: Can you poste a screenshot of your source and your destination?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the blue arrow.
Connect the blue arrow again between the source and the destination.
If it's not work, remove the destination and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the comments above:

This is how it looks like when i dont have mapped anything in my destination:

[image]

Now i did the mapping:

[image]

Comment: And if you did this mapping, then it must be another error? Maybe something about datatype? Your source columns needs to match destination columns datatype.